# Python class inherited from c++ via SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have c++ class, let's say `class A{ };` I created wrapper with SWIG to use this in python(file: wrapper.py).
Also I have Python class, which is inherited like this

```
class meta_A(type(wrapper.A)): pass
class derived(wrapper.A):
    __metaclass__ = meta_A
```

Now I got this issue,  when trying to instantiate class

```
class meta_A (type(wrapper.A)):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    type 'SwigPyObjectType' is not an acceptable base type
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: One solution is to use the `director` feature of SWIG

Comment: Can you back up a bit and explain what the end goal is here? It looks like you're making life harder than it needs to be, but I can't really tell how we got here.